# what is the optimal step size for metropolis-hastings algorithm to have independent state

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

In the PRML chapter 11, The Metropolis-Hasting algorithm,

For a sampler with Gaussian distribution as proposal distribution.

The original distribution is correlated multivariate Gaussian distribution, with standard deviations $\sigma_{min}$ and $\sigma_{max}$

The transition probability is shown as below: $q(z'|z) = \mathcal{N}(z, \rho^2I)$

Because the proposed distribution is symmetric, so  $q(z'|z) = q(z|z')$

Using Metropolis-hastings algorithm, the accept rate is

$A(z'|z)= min \left(1, \frac{\pi(z')q(z|z')}{\pi(z)q(z'|z)} \right)$

After cancel out the transition probability, we have

$A(z'|z)= min \left(1, \frac{\pi(z')}{\pi(z)} \right)$

It shown that the accept rate depends on the location of two points in the original distribution.

But I don't know how to include $\sigma_{max}$ or $\sigma_{min}$ in this equation.

And according to the article, the number of steps seperating states that are independent is order of $(\sigma_{max}/\sigma_{min})^2 $

How to generate this conclusion?

[image]

Comment: 1. The link to "the article" is missing. 2. The connection between $\rho$ and $(\sigma_\min,\sigma_\max)$ is not explicited.

Comment: @Xi'an, thank you, I just updated the missing information.  $\rho$ is the standard deviation of proposed transition probability. I don't know why choosing $\sigma_{min}$ as $\rho$ will help with accept rate